# How to split a file and keep the first line in each of the pieces?

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, text

**Given:** One big text-data file (e.g. CSV format) with a 'special' first line (e.g., field names).

**Wanted:** An equivalent of the coreutils `split -l` command, but with the additional requirement that the header line from the original file appear at the beginning of each of the resulting pieces.

I am guessing some concoction of `split` and `head` will do the trick?

Comment: It seems reasonable that someone should add that as a built-in feature of `split`, doesn't it?

Comment: Probably the biggest factor *against* this becoming a built-in is that you generally reconstruct a split file by doing `cat a b c > reconstructed`.  Extraneous lines in the file means the normal reconstruction approach does not reproduce the original file.

Comment: That's what the upcoming (*not*) "`unsplit --remove-header`" utility is for! But seriously, `split`, if it were to have a "repeat-header" option, should still default to its current behavior. You'd only use header stuff if you really wanted it.

Comment: Yes, I think `--keep-first N` would make a nice option for `split` which would be useful in both line and byte mode

Comment: *I* think it *is* a good idea -- absolutely very useful for splitting a file for *distribution* rather than reconstruction.  It's one of those "so simple, how is it not there yet" features of a Unix utility so old, that I'm skeptical that the "people in charge" haven't turned down previous proposals to do this exact functionality for some reason or another.

Comment: I think the reasoning might be simply due to the POSIX spec for split not having that option.  I can only imagine how difficult it is to add functionality to POSIX standards!  http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/split.html

Comment: I updated my answer with a cool feature that GNU `split` provides.

Comment: I found such a proposal at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2003-08/msg00022.html which wasn't so much flat-out turned down as discouraged ( because you ought to be able to write a script / program for that?? )

Comment: Related: [Split CSV files into smaller files but keeping the headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420966)

Comment: The best tool for this purpose is `xsv`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68585985/8079808

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This is **robhruska's** script cleaned up a bit:

```
tail -n +2 file.txt | split -l 4 - split_
for file in split_*
do
    head -n 1 file.txt > tmp_file
    cat "$file" >> tmp_file
    mv -f tmp_file "$file"
done
```

I removed `wc`, `cut`, `ls` and `echo` in the places where they're unnecessary. I changed some of the filenames to make them a little more meaningful. I broke it out onto multiple lines only to make it easier to read.

If you want to get fancy, you could use `mktemp` or `tempfile` to create a temporary filename instead of using a hard coded one.

**Edit**

Using GNU `split` it's possible to do this:

```
split_filter () { { head -n 1 file.txt; cat; } > "$FILE"; }; export -f split_filter; tail -n +2 file.txt | split --lines=4 --filter=split_filter - split_
```

Broken out for readability:

```
split_filter () { { head -n 1 file.txt; cat; } > "$FILE"; }
export -f split_filter
tail -n +2 file.txt | split --lines=4 --filter=split_filter - split_
```

When `--filter` is specified, `split` runs the command (a function in this case, which must be exported) for each output file and sets the variable `FILE`, in the command's environment, to the filename.

A filter script or function could do any manipulation it wanted to the output contents or even the filename. An example of the latter might be to output to a fixed filename in a variable directory: `> "$FILE/data.dat"` for example.

Comment: This will certainly work.  I was just hoping for some slick one-liner like `for $part in (split -l 1000 myfile); cat <(head -n1 myfile) $part > myfile.$part; done`

Comment: That can't work because `split`, of necessity, doesn't output on `stdout`.

Comment: `split` *could* output the *names* of the files to stdout, though (as long as we are discussing what `split` *ought* to do :-)

Comment: You're right. That could be *handy*. Sorry I misread your one-liner.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.10.4 worked with the original snippet, but not the one-liner GNU split version.

Comment: @JohnathanElmore: Note that GNU utilities are available for OS X. Using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), for example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30005262/1014710 has instructions for Homebrew GNU coreutils instructions

Comment: You may want to add `--additional-suffix=.txt` to the `split` command to keep the file extension

Answer (score 43):

This one-liner will split the big csv into pieces of 999 records, preserving the header row at the top of each one (so 999 records + 1 header = 1000 rows)

```
cat bigFile.csv | parallel --header : --pipe -N999 'cat >file_{#}.csv'
```

Based on Ole Tange's answer.

See comments for some tips on installing parallel

Comment: please noted that if we consider the header row in each file then each smaller file will have 1000 rows in this solution.

Comment: Which is why I use 999  :)

Comment: I had to `brew install parallel` on macOS. Works like a charm!

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: Like MacOS, Ubuntu 20.04 also needs to have `parallel` installed for this to work.

Note that Ubuntu suggests either `sudo apt install moreutils` _# version 0.63-1_, or `sudo apt install parallel` _# version 20161222-1.1_ -- go with the latter suggestion. The first suggestion, `moreutils` sounds extra useful, but the version of parallel included in that package errored out (`parallel: invalid option -- '-'`).  The second suggestion worked as expected ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19503387/697507)).

Answer (score 17):

You could use the new --filter functionality in GNU coreutils split >= 8.13 (2011):

```
tail -n +2 FILE.in | split -l 50 - --filter='sh -c "{ head -n1 FILE.in; cat; } > $FILE"'
```

Comment: I like the one-liner version. Just to make it more generic for bash, I did: `tail -n +2 FILE.in | split -d --lines 50 - --filter='bash -c "{ head -n1 ${FILE%.*}; cat; } > $FILE"' FILE.in.x`

Comment: Just a note for MacOS users. The default split included in MacOS is not compatible with the one used in this answer. You would need to install GNU's split: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/69223/301207

Answer (score 14):

You can use [mg]awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{
        header=$0; 
        count=1; 
        print header > "x_" count; 
        next 
     } 

     !( (NR-1) % 100){
        count++; 
        print header > "x_" count;
     } 
     {
        print $0 > "x_" count
     }' file
```

100 is the number of lines of each slice. 
It doesn't require temp files and can be put on a single line.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a novice when it comes to Bash-fu, but I was able to concoct this two-command monstrosity. I'm sure there are more elegant solutions.

```
$> tail -n +2 file.txt | split -l 4
$> for file in `ls xa*`; do echo "`head -1 file.txt`" > tmp; cat $file >> tmp; mv -f tmp $file; done
```

This is assuming your input file is `file.txt`, you're not using the `prefix` argument to `split`, and you're working in a directory that doesn't have any other files that start with `split`'s default `xa*` output format. Also, replace the '4' with your desired split line size.

Answer (score 4):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -a bigfile.csv --header : --pipepart 'cat > {#}'
```

If you need to run a command on each of the parts, then GNU Parallel can help do that, too:

```
parallel -a bigfile.csv --header : --pipepart my_program_reading_from_stdin
parallel -a bigfile.csv --header : --pipepart --fifo my_program_reading_from_fifo {}
parallel -a bigfile.csv --header : --pipepart --cat my_program_reading_from_a_file {}
```

If you want to split into 2 parts per CPU core (e.g. 24 cores = 48 equal sized parts):

```
parallel --block -2 -a bigfile.csv --header : --pipepart my_program_reading_from_stdin
```

If you want to split into 10 MB blocks:

```
parallel --block 10M -a bigfile.csv --header : --pipepart my_program_reading_from_stdin
```

Comment: "--block 10M" - a day saver!!

Answer (score 4):

Below is a 4 liner that can be used to split a bigfile.csv into multiple smaller files, and preserve the csv header. Uses only built-in Bash commands (head, split, find, grep, xargs, and sed) which should work on most *nix systems. Should also work on Windows if you install mingw-64 / git-bash.

```
csvheader=`head -1 bigfile.csv`
split -d -l10000 bigfile.csv smallfile_
find .|grep smallfile_ | xargs sed -i "1s/^/$csvheader\n/"
sed -i '1d' smallfile_00
```

Line by line explanation:

1. Capture the header to a variable named **csvheader**
2. Split the **bigfile.csv** into a number of smaller files with prefix **smallfile_**
3. **Find** all smallfiles and insert the csvheader into the FIRST line using **xargs** and **sed -i**. Note that you need to use sed within "double quotes" in order to use variables.
4. The first file named smallfile_00 will now have redundant headers on lines 1 and 2 (from the original data as well as from the sed header insert in step 3). We can remove the redundant header with sed -i '1d' command.

Comment: Getting below error:  `Error While executing report: Error: Command failed with exit code 123: find .|grep file_part_ | xargs sed -i "1s/^/column 1, column 2 /"sed: -e expression #1, char 78: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: @Subburaj Try removing any single/double quotes from the bigfile's header 
For example if you have `"column 1", "column 2"`  - then ideally it should look like :  `column 1, column 2`

Another option is to change the script's first line like this: 
<pre>
csvheader="column 1, column 2"
</pre>

Answer (score 2):

This is a more robust version of **Denis Williamson**'s script. The script creates a lot of temporary files, and it would be a shame if they were left lying around if the run was incomplete. So, let's add signal trapping (see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html and then http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/debugging.html) and remove our temporary files; this is a best practice anyways.

```
trap 'rm split_* tmp_file ; exit 13' SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT 
tail -n +2 file.txt | split -l 4 - split_
for file in split_*
do
    head -n 1 file.txt > tmp_file
    cat $file >> tmp_file
    mv -f tmp_file $file
done
```

Replace '13' with whatever return code you want. Oh, and you should probably be using mktemp anyways (as some have already suggested), so go ahead and remove 'tmp_file" from the rm in the trap line. See the signal man page for more signals to catch.

Answer (score 2):

I liked the awk version of marco, adopted from this a simplified one-liner where you can easily specify the split fraction as granular as you want:

```
awk 'NR==1{print $0 > FILENAME ".split1";  print $0 > FILENAME ".split2";} NR>1{if (NR % 10 > 5) print $0 >> FILENAME ".split1"; else print $0 >> FILENAME ".split2"}' file
```

Comment: I like this solution, however it's limited to only two split files

Comment: If you like it there is the upvote feature for it ;) It can easily be adjusted to more files, but yes it's not as flexible as split -l

Comment: "one liner" ...pshh

Answer (score 2):

I really liked Rob and Dennis' versions, so much so that I wanted to improve them.

Here's my version:

```
in_file=$1
awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}' $in_file | split -d -a 5 -l 100000 - $in_file"_" # Get all lines except the first, split into 100,000 line chunks
for file in $in_file"_"*
do
    tmp_file=$(mktemp $in_file.XXXXXX) # Create a safer temp file
    head -n 1 $in_file | cat - $file > $tmp_file # Get header from main file, cat that header with split file contents to temp file
    mv -f $tmp_file $file # Overwrite non-header containing file with header-containing file
done
```

Differences:

1. in_file is the file argument you want to split maintaining headers
2. Use `awk` instead of `tail` due to `awk` having better performance
3. split into 100,000 line files instead of 4
4. Split file name will be input file name appended with an underscore and numbers (up to 99999 - from the "-d -a 5" split argument)
5. Use mktemp to safely handle temporary files
6. Use single `head | cat` line instead of two lines

Comment: Suggestion: change awk script to simply: 'NR > 1'  as print is the default action.

Comment: That said, I doubt awk is any faster (or at least significantly faster) than tail in this case.

Comment: I also might put the header in a variable before the loop, and then 'echo "$header | ...." in the loop

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Arkady's comment on a one-liner.

- MYFILE variable simply to reduce boilerplate
- `split` doesn't show file name, but the `--additional-suffix` option allows us to easily control what to expect
- removal of intermediate files via `rm $part` (assumes no files with same suffix)

`MYFILE=mycsv.csv && for part in $(split -n4 --additional-suffix=foo $MYFILE; ls *foo); do cat <(head -n1 $MYFILE) $part > $MYFILE.$part; rm $part; done`

Evidence:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user  32040108 Jun  1 23:18 mycsv.csv.xaafoo
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user  32040108 Jun  1 23:18 mycsv.csv.xabfoo
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user  32040108 Jun  1 23:18 mycsv.csv.xacfoo
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user  32040110 Jun  1 23:18 mycsv.csv.xadfoo
```

and of course `head -2 *foo` to see the header is added.

Answer (score 0):

I had a better result using the following code, every split file will have a header and the generated files will have a normalized name.

```
export F=input.csv && LINES=3 &&\
export PF="${F%.*}_" &&\
split -l $LINES "${F}" "${PF}" &&\
for fn in $PF*
do
  mv "${fn}" "${fn}.csv"
done &&\
export FILES=($PF*) && for file in "${FILES[@]:1}"
do
  head -n 1 "${F}" > tmp_file
  cat "$file" >> tmp_file
  mv -f tmp_file "${file}"
done
```

output

```
$ wc -l input*
  22 input.csv
   3 input_aa.csv
   4 input_ab.csv
   4 input_ac.csv
   4 input_ad.csv
   4 input_ae.csv
   4 input_af.csv
   4 input_ag.csv
   2 input_ah.csv
  51 total
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple but maybe not as elegant way: Cut off the header beforehand, split the file, and then rejoin the header on each file with cat, or with whatever file is reading it in.
So something like:

1. head -n1 file.txt > header.txt
2. split -l file.txt
3. cat header.txt f1.txt