# How to split a file into equal parts, without breaking individual lines?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, split

I was wondering if it was possible to split a file into equal parts (*edit:* = all equal except for the last), without breaking the line? Using the split command in Unix, lines may be broken in half. Is there a way to, say, split up a file in 5 equal parts, but have it still only consist of whole lines (it's no problem if one of the files is a little larger or smaller)? I know I could just calculate the number of lines, but I have to do this for a lot of files in a bash script. Many thanks!

Comment: What's your definition of "equal" that allows for unequal file sizes?

Comment: All equal, except for one (probably the last one).

Comment: cross ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/54579/how-to-split-larger-files-into-smaller-parts#

Comment: one liner for equally split by N: (1.) split by lines `split --lines $(( $(wc -l < ${your_filename}) / ${N})) ${your_filename}` (2.) split by bytes `split --bytes $(( $(wc -c < ${your_filename}) / ${N})) ${your_filename}`

Answer (score 165, accepted):

If you mean an equal number of *lines,* `split` has an option for this:

```
split --lines=75
```

If you need to know what that `75` should really be for `N` equal parts, its:

```
lines_per_part = int(total_lines + N - 1) / N
```

where total lines can be obtained with `wc -l`.

See the following script for an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Configuration stuff

fspec=qq.c
num_files=6

# Work out lines per file.

total_lines=$(wc -l <${fspec})
((lines_per_file = (total_lines + num_files - 1) / num_files))

# Split the actual file, maintaining lines.

split --lines=${lines_per_file} ${fspec} xyzzy.

# Debug information

echo "Total lines     = ${total_lines}"
echo "Lines  per file = ${lines_per_file}"    
wc -l xyzzy.*
```

This outputs:

```
Total lines     = 70
Lines  per file = 12
  12 xyzzy.aa
  12 xyzzy.ab
  12 xyzzy.ac
  12 xyzzy.ad
  12 xyzzy.ae
  10 xyzzy.af
  70 total
```

---

More recent versions of `split` allow you to specify a number of `CHUNKS` with the `-n/--number` option. You can therefore use something like:

```
split --number=l/6 ${fspec} xyzzy.
```

(that's `ell-slash-six`, meaning `lines`, not `one-slash-six`).

That will give you roughly equal files in terms of size, with no mid-line splits.

I mention that last point because it doesn't give you roughly the same number of *lines* in each file, more the same number of *characters.*

So, if you have one 20-character line and 19 1-character lines (twenty lines in total) and split to five files, you most likely *won't* get four lines in every file.

Comment: That would split up my file in pieces of 75 lines.. But I was wondering if there was a split command option, where I could say for example that I want the file to be split up in 5 equal parts (without giving the nr of lines), and that would split up the file in 5 equal parts, each consisting of complete lines only.

Comment: Thanks, that script example was exactly what I needed!

Comment: One-line command to do similar thing in OS X...   split -l num_of_lines_per_file original_file destination_files.

Comment: For massive files (my test file is 83 million lines long), the above method to count lines is a little slow; you can actually pass the filename itself as an argument to `wc` without having to cat the whole file, e.g. `wc -l filename.txt`  `wc` outputs `<number_of_lines> <filename>` so you'd have to pipe the output to awk to grab the word count, but it's still significantly faster than `cat`ing the whole file and piping it to `wc`

Answer (score 46):

A simple solution for a simple question:

```
split -n l/5 your_file.txt
```

no need for scripting here.

From the [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) file, `CHUNKS  may  be:`

```
l/N     split into N files without splitting lines
```

**Update**

Not all unix dist include this flag. For example, it will not work in OSX. To use it, you can consider [replacing the Mac OS X utilities with GNU core utilities](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities).

Comment: for people reading.  FYI: that is L/N (with lower case L), not 1 (one)

Comment: I don't have that option in split. Is it new?

Comment: @kap answer updated

Answer (score 45):

The script isn't even necessary, [split(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) supports the wanted feature out of the box:
`split -l 75 auth.log auth.log.` 
The above command splits the file in chunks of 75 lines a piece, and outputs file on the form: `auth.log.aa, auth.log.ab, ...`

`wc -l` on the original file and output gives:

```
  321 auth.log
   75 auth.log.aa
   75 auth.log.ab
   75 auth.log.ac
   75 auth.log.ad
   21 auth.log.ae
  642 total
```

Answer (score 24):

split was updated in [coreutils release 8.8](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=6662) (announced 22 Dec 2010) with the --number option to generate a specific number of files. The option --number=l/n generates n files without splitting lines.

[coreutils manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html#split-invocation)

Comment: +1 i believe this is the correct response to OPs question without getting to complicated. Also the answer I needed

Answer (score 6):

I made a bash script, that given a number of parts as input, split a file

```
#!/bin/sh

parts_total="$2";
input="$1";

parts=$((parts_total))
for i in $(seq 0 $((parts_total-2))); do
  lines=$(wc -l "$input" | cut -f 1 -d" ")
  #n is rounded, 1.3 to 2, 1.6 to 2, 1 to 1
  n=$(awk  -v lines=$lines -v parts=$parts 'BEGIN { 
    n = lines/parts;
    rounded = sprintf("%.0f", n);
    if(n>rounded){
      print rounded + 1;
    }else{
      print rounded;
    }
  }');
  head -$n "$input" > split${i}
  tail -$((lines-n)) "$input" > .tmp${i}
  input=".tmp${i}"
  parts=$((parts-1));
done
mv .tmp$((parts_total-2)) split$((parts_total-1))
rm .tmp*
```

I used `head` and `tail` commands, and store in tmp files, for split the files

```
#10 means 10 parts
sh mysplitXparts.sh input_file 10
```

or with awk, where 0.1 is 10% => 10 parts, or 0.334 is 3 parts

```
awk -v size=$(wc -l < input) -v perc=0.1 '{
  nfile = int(NR/(size*perc)); 
  if(nfile >= 1/perc){
    nfile--;
  } 
  print > "split_"nfile
}' input
```

Comment: this is a **way better** answer than the selected one

Answer (score 1):

```
var dict = File.ReadLines("test.txt")
               .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line))
               .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2, 0))
               .ToDictionary(parts => parts[0], parts => parts[1]);


or 

    enter code here

line="to=xxx@gmail.com=yyy@yahoo.co.in";
string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2, 0);

ans:
tokens[0]=to
token[1]=xxx@gmail.com=yyy@yahoo.co.in"
```