# How to split a 4GB SQL file into queries using the command line

Tags: regex, unix, split

I am trying to split a 4GB SQL file into smaller files so that I can import them one by one to reduce errors.

Each `INSERT` statement starts on a new line and is preceded by `);`

I have tried using `split -p \0\;INSERT` but this does not work.

I have read about `csplit` however I am still unssure as to what RegularExpression is needed.

There are 117 tables across the 4GB of data.

A sample `INSERT` statement is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO 'puid' VALUES (2196534,'ee1d9e3f-b3ae-e36b-cfea-2499a18bd86e',163);
INSERT INTO 'puid' VALUES (2196535,'e2c05e1c-73bd-cdc7-0bab-610b6afe4bd7',163);
```

Comment: Can you give a few lines of examples?

Comment: Example of the SQL file? Or other things I have tried?

Comment: The content of the file.

Comment: One `INSERT` statement is just over 1MB in size and is too large to post here.

Comment: You can just trim most of it, and show minimal examples. Such as `INSERT INTO table ('test');` or something

Comment: `INSERT INTO 'puid' VALUES (2196534,'ee1d9e3f-b3ae-e36b-cfea-2499a18bd86e',163);` `INSERT INTO 'puid' VALUES (2196535,'e2c05e1c-73bd-cdc7-0bab-610b6afe4bd7',163);`

Comment: Put that into your question, not here. =)

Comment: If that's the case, it's quite simple to do just like written in this answer, no? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764755/unix-how-to-split-a-file-into-equal-parts-without-breaking-individual-lines?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `split -l <line_count>`? That'll split on line boundaries.