# Splitting file based on quantity of lines, each part save to one file AWK, BASH

Tags: bash, awk

Good day to all,

I was wondering how to split a file based on the quantity of number lines, this number passed as variable and each part has the same size (same line numbers), and each part save it into a file.

This is what I have tried:

```
awk -v var="$1" ' FNR==var {close("Partfile"f);f++}{print $0 > "Partfile"f}' datafile
```

Thanks in advance for any clue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unix: How to split a file into equal parts, without breaking individual lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764755/unix-how-to-split-a-file-into-equal-parts-without-breaking-individual-lines)

Comment: mmm... nope, I don't care about the integrity of the line and I request on awk, not on split

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output as your question is open to interpretation in several different ways. And make the input the difficult cases to handle, not the easy ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `split`

```
split -l 20 file Partfile
```

to split in lumps of 20 lines each.

Comment: Referee! Red Card! :-) @triplee in the very first comment told Alejandro his question is a dup of one with a `split` solution and Alejandro argued that he wanted an `awk` solution, not a `split` one, and then he accepted the answer using `split`!

Comment: @EdMorton Some OPs, eh?

Comment: I'll tell yah... ;-).

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -v var="$1" '(FNR % var) == 1 { ++n; close(f); f = "Partfile" n } { print > f }' datafile
```

Comment: Thanks, please, can you explain me this part: `(FNR % var) == 1`

Comment: @Alejandro For every start of the set, `FNR % var` would always be 1. See a discussion about modulus: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54363.html