# how to stop process when last record is reached (the number of records are not known)

Tags: r

I have a file of size 2.5 GB and my RAM size is 4 GB.
I do not know the number of records in the file.
I want to break this file into 5 parts(chunk) of 500 MBs each ( approx. 2000000 records per part or chunk).

While doing this I have a problem that how to tell R that you have reached the last line , so please end the process and through the last file of whatever size it is of.

code I'm using is below:

```
f<- file(file.choose(),"r")     # file given here is of 2.5 GB       

for(i in 1:4){
  ab <-sprintf('d_%d',i)
  write.csv(read.table(f,nrows=1600000,blank.lines.skip = TRUE,),
            file=sprintf('%s.csv',ab))
}
```

Error is:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  line 1446670 did not have 10 elements
```

So how to tell my program that as and when it reaches the last record, stop process and through the last chunk of whatever size it is formed?

Comment: Use the right tool for the job, split it outsite R (or within R, `system()`) then read in. See: [Unix: How to split a file into equal parts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764755/unix-how-to-split-a-file-into-equal-parts-without-breaking-individual-lines)

Comment: By the way error indicates something is wrong with delimiters: `line 1446670 did not have 10 elements`

Comment: that record has some missing data (6 elements missing),but I do not want the process to end here.It should continue and ends only when last record is reached