# Writing huge ArrayList to file in a human readable format

Tags: java, arraylist, filewriter, large-data

I have a program that processes quite a lot of sensor data from a sensor system. I'm currently looking into writing the output from my program to a text file so that I can check if it is processes properly from the program.

Right now I am writing a few identifiers before the ArrayList and then writing the ArrayList to the file using `ArrayList.toString()`.

```
lineToWrite = identifer1 + ";" + identifier2 + ";" + ArrayList.toString()
```

The output file contains 21 lines in total, and the ArrayLists are from 100 items to 400.000 items large. Using the `toString()` method makes it impossible for any of the file editing programs I usually use to open the file and inspect them.

I thought of doing a small processing of the items in the ArrayList:

```
String lineToWrite = "";

String arrayListString = "\n";
for(String s : sensorLine){
    arrayListString += "\t" + s + "\n";
}

lineToWrite = identifer1 + ";" + identifier2 + ";" + arrayListString;
```

but it seems like this takes forever for some of the ArrayLists which are large enough. Does anyone have a better/faster approach for doing this or know of a good file viewing program?

I have used the following, which don't have the following problems:

- Notepad++ -> Slow to open and laggy once fully opened
- Sublime Text 3 -> Very slow to open!

As a small side note to the sensor data: I have in total 2.3 million sensor inputs.

## EDIT1:

To extend the problem question I might have to add that it is the part of splitting the enormous array into a single string that proved to be a problem. The program iterates very slowly over the array as it is just increasing the size of the `arrayListString` on every pass through and that takes up a lot of memory/processing power I guess.

## EDIT2:

As for the writing method itself I am using a `BufferedWriter()`, with placeholders for the actual method variables:

```
output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename, toAppend), "UTF-8"));
```

And for the actual writing I am using:

```
output.append(line)
output.flush();
```

Comment: `+` is an awful and the main performance killer, and I don't think if it's replaced with `StringBuilder` efficiently. Did you consider data streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found a solution.

I used a `StringBuilder` to surpass the problem of writing a huge string to the file. The approach is as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : arrayList){
    sb.append("\t" + s + "\n"
}

String line = identifier1 + ";" + identfier2 + ";" + sb.toString();
```

And for the editor **Sublime Text 3** didn't seem to mind too much as long as the lines weren't 400.000 characters long

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you're assembling a very large string into memory, and then writing it all at once, with lots of string manipulation to boot (leading to allocation of memory for each string).

Instead, look into using a Stream.  Use a Writer, and you can iterate the array and append to a file as you go, will be much faster.

Here's a good tutorial on the basics:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm

As to the editor issue, most editors either load the entire file into memory or load it in chunks of lines or bytes.  If you have huge lines, you may want to revisit your format.

Comment: Hundred times faster to write.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to split your data into chunks and load into editor when needed.Here a good answer.
[How to read Text File of about 2 GB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208524/how-to-read-text-file-of-about-2-gb)

Answer (score 2):

Dump the data into a **database**.

Then you can do interesting things like select the numbers 1000 - 1100, or search values, do avg/min/max. In a database client like Toad.

The SQL query language should not be a problem. A client also not.

Java has embedded, standalone databases; H2 might suffice.

Comment: Would be my go to approach, however I currently need to verify the algorithm that the data passes through before it goes into a database storage. This is the reason behind storing it to a file. Anyway. Thanks for the suggestion! :D

Answer (score 1):

For some odd reason, nearly all text editors hare horribly slow when you have **long lines**. Often you can easily edit a file with a million lines, but will encounter problems if the file contains a single line with 100000 characters.

Regarding the performance of *writing* a file, there are several trade-offs.

It is generally beneficial for performance to write "larger blocks of data". That is: When you want to write 1000 bytes, you should write these 1000 bytes at once, and not one by one. But in this case, you are attempting to build a *really* huge block of data by assembling a huge string. This may strike back and decrease the performance, becase assembling this string may be expensive due to the many string concatenations.

As [Taylor pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39595852/3182664), writing the file line-by-line is likely a reasonable trade-off here: The chunks are then still large enough to compensate for the efforts of the write operation in general, and still small enough to avoid string concatenation overheads.

As an example: The time for writing 1 Million lines with a `BufferedWriter` should hardly be measurable:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayListToFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        List<String> sensorLine = new ArrayList<String>();
        int size = 1000000;
        Random random = new Random(0);
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            sensorLine.add(String.valueOf(random.nextDouble()));
        }

        write("out.txt", sensorLine);
    }

    private static void write(String fileName, Iterable<?> elements)
        throws IOException
    {
        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName))))
        {
            String identifier1 = "i1";
            String identifier2 = "i2";

            bw.write(identifier1 + ";" + identifier2 + ";\n");

            for (Object s : elements)
            {
                bw.write("\t" + s + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like your suggestion about writing the `sensorlines` separately from the rest of the data. I'm not sure if it is faster than my current approach. I went with a `StringBuilder`. It seems really fast to compute a total string element that I can just write once. Instead of doing up to 400.000 write commands.

Comment: Yes, `StringBuilder` may (in some cases) avoid much of the string concatenation overhead. However, one point to consider might be that when you do not have 400 thousand but 400 million lines, you might run out of memory at some point. Writing the lines individually (in a "streaming" fashion), and may scale better then. But when your current solution is OK for you, that's fine.