# How can I split one text file into multiple *.txt files?

Tags: linux, bash

I got a text file `file.txt` (12 MB) containing:

```
something1
something2
something3
something4
(...)
```

Is there a way to split `file.txt` into 12 *.txt files, let’s say `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`, `file4.txt`, etc.?

Comment: Related: [Unix & Linux: Create a tar archive split into blocks of a maximum size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/61774/114401)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use the Linux Bash core utility `split`:

```
split -b 1M -d  file.txt file
```

Note that `M` or `MB` both are OK but size is different. MB is 1000 * 1000, M is 1024^2

If you want to separate by lines you can use `-l` parameter.

**UPDATE**

```
a=(`wc -l yourfile`) ; lines=`echo $(($a/12)) | bc -l` ; split -l $lines -d  file.txt file
```

Another solution as suggested by [Kirill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115669/kirill),  you can do something like the following

```
split -n l/12 file.txt
```

Note that is `l` not `one`, `split -n` has a few options, like `N`, `k/N`, `l/k/N`, `r/N`, `r/k/N`.

Comment: Can you please update how it could be made sure that number of files are even without splitting the lines in it just by using `split`?

Comment: you can use `wc -l` to get the total lines and run something like this `a=(`wc -l yourfile`) ; lines=`echo $a/12 | bc -l` ; split -l=$lines -d  file.txt file`

Comment: With all those complexities you could have just use awk. And that won't worked with non-file input which won't allow reading the data twice. Just saying that your previous claim that `split` could do it isn't really correct. And as expected you used `wc`.

Comment: Nice update, personally glad you didn't use awk as line counts can be achieved without a full file read. 

By this logic, you can also `a=(\`wc -c yourfile\`) ; n=12; bytes=\`echo (a-a%n)/n\` | bc -l\` ; split -b=$bytes -d file.txt file` and to split evenly with the last file being the trailing bytes if you don't use divisible numbers. Derivatives of your method seem very easy to adjust!

Comment: Macos seems to prefer the size to be in lower case, that means `-b=1M` should be `-b=1m` for this to work.

Comment: Based on the manual page for `split`, the units are K, M, G, T, P, E, Z, Y, etc

Comment: Or just use split -n l/12 file.txt to get 12 files, splitted by line

Answer (score 85):

```
$ split -l 100 input_file output_file
```

where `-l` is the number of lines in each files. This will create:

- output_fileaa
- output_fileab
- output_fileac
- output_filead
- ....

Comment: How does it pick the aa, ab, ac...?

Comment: @T.BrianJones its taken care by split

Comment: Personally, I prefer using `-d` to make split use numeric suffixes.

Comment: Is there a way to know how many files have been created? And I don't mean counting them manually, I mean does the command split output that or is there a command line argument to tell it to output that?

Comment: To find the number of lines do `wc -l <filename>`

Answer (score 35):

CS Pei's answer won't produce .txt files as the OP wants. Use:

```
split -b=1M -d  file.txt file --additional-suffix=.txt
```

Comment: This is very helpful `--additional-suffix=.txt`

Comment: There is no one here by the name "John". What answer does it refer to?

Comment: Good question. Must be CS Pei. Will edit.

Comment: I have no idea on which operating system the option `-b=1M` works. But on Ubuntu and Centos, the option `-b=1M` will complain error "split: =1M: invalid number of bytes". The correct option is `-b 1M` or `--bytes=1M`. The space is required for short option.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#What-is-Bash_003f):

```
readarray -t lines < file.txt
count=${#lines[@]}

for i in "${!lines[@]}"; do
    index=$(( (i * 12 - 1) / count + 1 ))
    echo "${lines[i]}" >> "file${index}.txt"
done
```

Using [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
awk '{
    a[NR] = $0
}
END {
    for (i = 1; i in a; ++i) {
        x = (i * 12 - 1) / NR + 1
        sub(/\..*$/, "", x)
        print a[i] > "file" x ".txt"
    }
}' file.txt
```

Unlike `split`, this one makes sure that the number of lines are most even.

Comment: `split` can do that too

Comment: @JohnSmith Yeah didn't see the option quickly.

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm taking that back. How do we make sure that lines are even? Without using `wc -l` and calculating it of course or else we could have just use bash itself or awk. And that's actually the reason why I made the script and didn't consider split.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless to what was said in previous answers, on my [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) I had to do:

```
split -b 10M -d  system.log system_split.log
```

Please note the *space* between `-b` and the value.

Comment: Wouldn't that create `system_split.log1`, `system_split.log2`, etc without the `additional-suffix` option?

Comment: Yes it will do that

Answer (score 1):

My search of how to do this led  me here, so I'm posting this here for others too:

To get *all* of the contents of the file, `split` is the right answer! But, for those looking to just *extract* a *piece* of a file, as a sample of the file, use `head` or `tail`:

```bash
# extract just the **first** 100000 lines of /var/log/syslog into 
# ~/syslog_sample.txt
head -n 100000 /var/log/syslog > ~/syslog_sample.txt

# extract just the **last** 100000 lines of /var/log/syslog into 
# ~/syslog_sample.txt
tail -n 100000 /var/log/syslog > ~/syslog_sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
awk -vc=1 'NR%1000000==0{++c}{print $0 > c".txt"}' Datafile.txt

for filename in *.txt; do mv "$filename" "Prefix_$filename"; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @CS Pei, however this didn't work for me:

`split -b=1M -d  file.txt file`

...as the `=` after `-b` threw it off. Instead, I simply deleted it and left no space between it and the variable, and used lowercase "m":

`split -b1m -d  file.txt file`

And to append ".txt", we use what @schoon said:

`split -b=1m -d  file.txt file --additional-suffix=.txt`

I had a 188.5MB txt file and I used this command [but with `-b5m` for 5.2MB files], and it returned 35 split files all of which were txt files and 5.2MB except the last which was 5.0MB.   Now, since I wanted my lines to stay whole, I wanted to split the main file every 1 million lines, but the `split` command didn't allow me to even do `-100000` let alone "`-1000000`, so large numbers of lines to split will not work.

Comment: You just need the `-C` option of `split`.

Answer (score 0):

On my Linux system (Red Hat Enterprise 6.9), the `split` command does not have the command-line options for either `-n` or `--additional-suffix`.

Instead, I've used this:

```
split -d -l NUM_LINES really_big_file.txt split_files.txt.
```

where `-d` is to add a numeric suffix to the end of the `split_files.txt.` and `-l` specifies the number of lines per file.

For example, suppose I have a really big file like this:

```
$ ls -laF
total 1391952
drwxr-xr-x 2 user.name group         40 Sep 14 15:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 user.name group       4096 Sep 14 15:39 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 user.name group 1425352817 Sep 14 14:01 really_big_file.txt
```

This file has 100,000 lines, and I want to split it into files with at most 30,000 lines. This command will run the split and append an integer at the end of the output file pattern `split_files.txt.`.

```
$ split -d -l 30000 really_big_file.txt split_files.txt.
```

The resulting files are split correctly with at most 30,000 lines per file.

```
$ ls -laF
total 2783904
drwxr-xr-x 2 user.name group        156 Sep 14 15:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 user.name group       4096 Sep 14 15:39 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 user.name group 1425352817 Sep 14 14:01 really_big_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user.name group  428604626 Sep 14 15:43 split_files.txt.00
-rw-r--r-- 1 user.name group  427152423 Sep 14 15:43 split_files.txt.01
-rw-r--r-- 1 user.name group  427141443 Sep 14 15:43 split_files.txt.02
-rw-r--r-- 1 user.name group  142454325 Sep 14 15:43 split_files.txt.03


$ wc -l *.txt*
    100000 really_big_file.txt
     30000 split_files.txt.00
     30000 split_files.txt.01
     30000 split_files.txt.02
     10000 split_files.txt.03
    200000 total
```

Answer (score 0):

If each part has the same number of lines, for example 22, here is my solution:

```
split --numeric-suffixes=2 --additional-suffix=.txt -l 22 file.txt file
```

And you obtain *file2.txt* with the first 22 lines, *file3.txt* the 22 next line, etc.

Thank @hamruta-takawale, @dror-s and @stackoverflowuser2010