# csv data for spilting in different files

Tags: linux, csv, vim

```
   25422572,2018-04-01,00:00:27,e7961e25-5f46-4c81-b85d-36ce404bf72e,891672
   25422631,2018-04-01,00:01:21,41afad62-c037-4bed-9568-f76f3a86eb10,891672,
```

I have a data like shown above, up to 2018-04-30 .I want to split it down in 3 files for 10 days each. How can I do this through Linux commands ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? To prevent downvotes please see:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
- maybe ask a search engine first for "linux split text file pattern" to get a starting point. after that edit your answer where you got stuck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a large text file into smaller files with equal number of lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-to-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-equal-number-of-lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use grep:

```
grep -E "2018-04-(0[1-9]|10)" input.txt > out1.txt                            
grep -E "2018-04-(1[1-9]|20)" input.txt > out2.txt                            
grep -E "2018-04-(2[1-9]|30)" input.txt > out3.txt
```