# How to split a large document using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I want to split a long `text.csv` text file of say 2 x 400,000 size into 80 smaller files (2 x 6000). Ideally, I want to write each smaller file on to my disk as text1.csv, text2.csv etc. What is the most efficient way to do this?

```
         col 1         col2
0        text          text
1        text          text
2        text          text
...
399999   text          text
400000   text          text
```

The smaller files would look like this:

```
         col 1         col2
0        text          text
1        text          text
2        text          text
...
4999     text          text
5000     text          text


         col 1         col2
5001     text          text
5002     text          text
5003     text          text
...
9999     text          text
10000    text          text

etc.
```

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Comment: I would not write anything for this myself, but use the split command on the shell - or possibly call that as an external program from python. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-to-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-equal-number-of-lines

Comment: @rje: is it that simple? Can you post this as an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: @twhale done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not write anything for this myself, but use the split command on the shell - or possibly call that as an external program from python. See:

[How to split a large text file into smaller files with equal number of lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-to-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-equal-number-of-lines)

Comment: `split` will not add the headers shown in the example.