# VI shows control characters after splitting a large text file with git bash split

Tags: vim, split, vi, git-bash

I used [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-to-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-equal-number-of-lines) to split a large text file into several smaller files. To split the file I use the following command in Git Bash:

> split -l 80000 largeFile

I then want to edit each of the output files, but when I open them in VI, the output looks weird and I cannot properly edit the file. The output contains a lot of `@` symbols and carets. I assume that these are control characters. See the following screenshot:

[image]

My questions are:

- Why is the file displayed like this?
- How can I properly edit the file in VI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely, every second character is `^@`, which inside Vim represent a *null* byte (cp. [`:help <Nul>`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#%3CNul%3E)). The letters in between are readable (`USE [TIP_Update_...`). So what we're looking at is a 16-bit encoding (i.e. two bytes for each character) of (mostly?) ASCII text; as the null byte is the second one, it is *little endian*.

The first two characters (`ÿþ`) break the rule; this is a [*byte order mark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that provides text editors with a hint what the encoding is. The way it is displayed, Vim instead thinks the text is in `latin1` encoding.

So, you're dealing with *16 bit UCS-2 encoded Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646-1)* (name in Vim: `ucs-2le`; see [`:help encoding-values`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/mbyte.txt.html#encoding-values)), but Vim doesn't detect them automatically.

You can either

- manually force the encoding via [`:help ++enc`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%2B%2Benc): `:e! ++enc=ucs-2le`
- reconfigure Vim ([`:help 'fileencodings'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27fileencodings%27)) to automatically detect these; actually, the default value includes `ucs-bom` and should detect these just fine.

Comment: thanks, this worked great for the first file of the splitted output, but for the second one it doesn't work. the result looks like this: https://pasteboard.co/HSrgkz9.png the file initially looks like this: https://pasteboard.co/HSrgyNm.png  the difference is that the first two characters (ÿþ) do not appear here. can you provide a working command?

Comment: That looks like the split wasn't on an even byte count, so the second one is actually _big-endian_ (with corruption at the borders). If you really need to split on _lines_, your shell also needs to have a correct understanding of the encoding. It would be easier to split on (even!) byte counts, e.g. `split -b 800000`).

Comment: And if you supply the encoding manually, the lack of BOM doesn't matter. For `'fileencodings'`, it would complicate things, though.

Comment: thanks. however, even when using the command `split -b 100000000 largeFile` the second file looks like this: https://pasteboard.co/HSrQzvI.png but it seems that I can make it work with the command you provided: `:e! ++enc=ucs-2le`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant; you need the manual `++enc` as the BOM is missing from subsequent splits.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old post but it might help someone. If you are using Git Bash to Split the file into multiple files, try creating main file in 65001 ( UTF-8 ) instead of ANSI 1252 or any other. I was facing same issues of NUL in my splitted files but when I converted my main file into UTF-8, it worked perfectly fine.

```
SPLIT -l 50000 Main.txt Split.txt
```