# How can I use Regex in a While Loop in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, while-loop

I've to do the Regex in a While loop bc its to much data to do it in once. By now I can go throw the Data and the regex also works but the Data get not stored. So How can I do this?

This is my code now:

```
$handle = @fopen($PathToFile, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        if (preg_match_all('/^\w+\s+\d+\s('. $SelectedTime .':\d+.\d+).\d+.\d+\s(.+)/im', $buffer, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
            $decodeData[] .= $matches;
        }
        else {

        }
    }

var_dump($decodeData);
}
fclose($handle);
```

For help I would be really glad

Comment: What var_dump return ? I think you should rather use `$decodeData[] = $matches;` instead of `$decodeData[] .= $matches;`

Comment: @executable It returns: ```array(301140) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Array"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Array"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Array"
  [3]=> ....}```

Comment: So what is the problem here ?

Comment: Are you aware that you're potentially closing non opened file? Probably not, you also use `@`...

Comment: u are already storing in array `$decodeData[]` why are you concatenation> `.= `

Comment: for large file i think u need to store `$buffer` in an array then you can break this array in chunks by using `array_chunks()` then u can use regex and store result in a new array

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong syntax, it is not a string concatenation.

Instead of

```
$decodeData[] .= $matches;
```

Output:

> $decodeData[0] = "Result1Result2Result3Result4";

Use

```
$decodeData[] = $matches;
```

Output:

> $decodeData[0] = "Result1";
>   $decodeData[1] = "Result2";
>   $decodeData[2] = "Result3";
>   $decodeData[3] = "Result4";

Comment: If I try this I get: ```PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted```

Comment: @User9123 how big is your file?

Comment: @Nik - I added output examples to your answer for clarity

Comment: How large is your file?

Comment: this got nothing with syntax.

Comment: @Martin 591973500 bytes, bc its that big I made this loop

Comment: for large file i think u need to store $buffer in an array then you can break this array in chunks by using array_chunks() then u can use regex and store result in a new array

Comment: @User9123: if you cant then try with `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all` this will reduce load time. and share the result,

Comment: @devpro I get ```preg_match(): Invalid flags specified```

Comment: @User9123 you need to increase `memory_limit` in `php.ini` or using `ini_set` or flush the `$decodeData` array after X iterations somewhere. What is your PHP version?

Comment: @Nik I've the version: 
```PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies```
  And I cant increase the ```memory_limit``` because its already really high

Comment: Then you should think where to store your matches to avoid keep all in memory (php is not good with this). You can write the target matches into a csv file or into a database or into a memcache (depends what is best for you) to use them later.

Comment: @Nik I need the matches for some statistic. After the regex I convert the Data to a JSON File. So I've to filter this data. And this works also for smaller files with like 10000 to 30000 Records but if I have like 13000000 Records its crashing

Comment: Well, your script simple can not put all the entries into memory (php array). Try to split the files into chunks before processing or use bigger server. Other options I mentioned above.

Comment: @Nik please a sample

Comment: How to split files see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-to-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-equal-number-of-lines

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/preg_quote) function to escape `$SelectedTime` variable correctly and use `$decodedData[] = $matches` without `.=`.

```php
$handle = @fopen($PathToFile, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $pattern = '/^\w+\s+\d+\s('. preg_quote($SelectedTime) .':\d+.\d+).\d+.\d+\s(.+)/im';
        if (preg_match_all($pattern, $buffer, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
            $decodeData[] = $matches; // just assignment operator
        }
        else {

        }
    }

var_dump($decodeData);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: I get the same Error: ```PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted```

Comment: Try to do with a small file, for testing purposes. If works, you can change the `memory_limit` directive of `php.ini` file.

Comment: Do you now any other way without editing the ```memory_limt```