# Import only partial CSV in Sublime

Tags: csv, sublimetext3

How can I import, lets say 1000 lines, from a `CSV` file into Sublime?

I cannot find any settings in Sublime that let me perform this action. 
I do not want to import the whole file, since it will take a considerable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, SublimeText can't open 'half' a file.

I've faced the same issue, ended up with [splitting the large file into multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-to-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-equal-number-of-lines), and opening the one I needed;

```
# Split large file in small files containing 10000 lines
split -l 10000 mylargefile.csv
```

Comment: Ah I see. I thought maybe it had a feature like IntelliJ, where it only displays the first 1000 lines if the file is too large.

Comment: The best you could do in this regard is a plugin that manually loads in only part of the file, but there's no way for a plugin to prompt you for a file to open without actually opening it in Sublime at the same time (and it would have to try and put the changes back on save manually as well).