# Divide large text file in small text file python

Tags: python

I tried this script to divide a large text file (1 GB) into several small text file, but when I execute it, only an empty TXT file is created named "file1.txt"

```
chunksize = 1000000
fid = 1
with open('texto.txt', encoding="utf-8") as infile:
    print("opened correctly")
    f = open('file%d.txt' % fid, 'w')
    for i, line in enumerate(infile):
        print(i)
        f.write(line)
        print(i, chunksize)
        if not i % chunksize:
            f.close()
            fid += 1
            f = open('file%d.txt' % fid, 'w')
    f.close()
```

When I try with a small text file the code works fine

Comment: Just to be sure python is absolute requirement... 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-to-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-equal-number-of-lines

Comment: @yosukesabai yes

Comment: When I ran this script with `chunksize = 2` it executed correctly and created text files according to chunksize.

Comment: @ZainArshad try it with a 1gb text file

Comment: It works with a large file with two caveats:  It outputs one line to the first file, and if the file isn't 7-bit clean, it may produce odd results since you don't set the encoding for the output files.

Comment: This code works as expected for me (although file1.txt ends up containing only one line, because `enumerate()` starts at zero.)

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right directory for the output files?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, I'm sure

Comment: How many empty output files are you seeing?  Just one?

Comment: The marked duplicate focuses more on chooses the correct line count; you simply replace that with your chunk size.