# Split Output into multiple CSVs

Tags: windows, powershell, acl, fileserver

I have a txt with 19 500 000 of lines (each line is a full path of file or folder). I need to go with a foreach loop and get the ACLs, later save the output into CSV, but I need to split this CSV in files every 1000 lines.

I am at a loss; I appreciate any help or recommendation.

Comment: Look into `Get-Content` with the `-ReadCount` parameter. Should be what you're looking for

Comment: >Please refer [this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-can-i-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-an-equal-number-of-lin) to fulfil your question

Answer (score 1):

As [Abraham Zinala mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69512035/split-output-into-multiple-csvs#comment122864993_69512035), you might want to take advantage of `Get-Content -ReadCount`, to read the file in chunks of 1000 lines at a time, then output to CSV and continue with the next chunk:

```
$outputCounter = 1

Get-Content path\to\huge\file.txt -ReadCount 1000 |ForEach-Object {
  # Iterate over file paths in chunk, fetch ACL information, then write all 1000 records to a new CSV file
  $_ |ForEach-Object {
    Get-Item -LiteralPath $_ -PipelineVariable item |Get-ACL |Select @{Name='Path';Expression={$item.FullName}},Owner -ExpandProperty Access
  } |Export-Csv ".\path\to\output_${outputCounter}.csv" -NoTypeInformation

  # Increment output file counter
  $outputCounter++
}
```

Comment: Hey guys... Thanks for your comments... I am testing.