# Split a large json file into multifile with size within a certain range

Tags: json, linux, split

I have a large json file (~10GB) like this

```
{"id":1, "attributes":{"a": 1}}
{"id":2, "attributes":{"a": 4, "b": 5, "d": 6}}
{"id":2, "attributes":{"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6, "d": 5, "e": 1}}
{"id":2, "attributes":{"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6, "d": 5, "e": 1, h: "l"}}
```

I need split this file into multifile with size within a certain range (300-350MB)

I tried using split command line

```
split -l 5000000 test.json
```

or

```
split -b 300MB test.json
```

Both ways don't work as I expected because each line of json file has different size. If divided by size, the size of each file after splitting can be larger or smaller than the range I want. If divided by line, the last line or first line of the files after the split may be cut off

Comment: *"I have a large json file (~10GB)"* It's time to use a RDBMS. And your JSON is invalid by the way

Comment: [You can use the split command and ensure it splits on a line break with -C while still telling it the size.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2016918/3585500)