# SCP large number of files in small chunks from Server A to Server B

Tags: linux, scp

I have 1.5 milion files in single directory on Server A and I have a script which will move these to Server B.
Currently my script moves all the files at one go.

I am looking for a process where I can move files in chunk.
For Example: Moving 10000 files at each time
That means when I run the script, it will first move 10000 files, then sleep for few minutes, then move the next 10000 files and so on.
All files are of 3KB size.

Current Script I am using is as below

Is there any way to move files in chunk?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

username="eip"
origin="/origin"
backup="/origin/processed"
destination="/dest"
ip="abc.xyz.def"

dt=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)

echo "Uploading files to remote server..."
for file in "$origin"/*.xml
do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue    # In case there are no files to copy

    name=${file%.*}               # Strip extension
    name=${name##*/}              # Strip leading path
    save="${name}_$dt.xml"        # Backup filename with datetime suffix

    echo "Name is: $name"
    echo "File is: $file"

    echo "Copying file from Server A to Server B"
    scp -C -- "$file" "$username@$ip:$destination"

    echo "New file is: $backup/$save"
    echo "Moving file from Server A $origin to $backup and appending timestamp before file type"
    mv -f -- "$file" "$backup/$save"
done
echo 'File upload to remote server completed! ;)'
```

Comment: You can e.g. dump `ls` of all your file paths into a file, and use a [`split`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2016918/8564999) command to make files containing chunks of your filepaths. Then in your script iterate through those chunk files, read the filepaths from the file, `scp` or `rsync` them, sleep, go to the next chunk file