# GNU parallel not working at all

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu, xargs, gnu-parallel

I have been trying to use GNU parallel for some time, but I have never been able to get it to function at all!

For example, running (in a non-empty directory!):

```
ls | parallel echo            # Outputs single new line
ls | parallel echo echo echo  # Outputs three new lines.
ls | parallel echo {}         # /bin/bash: {}: command not found
ls | parallel echo '{}'       # /bin/bash: {}: command not found
ls | parallel 'echo {}'       # Outputs: {}
ls | parallel -IMM 'echo MM'  # Outputs: MM
```

It seems that it is simply executing each argument as a command, which makes no sense.

I have tried bash, zsh, tcsh, csh, and sh, to no avail.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

As I was about to complete writing this question, I ran `parallel --version` to report the version, only to find:

> WARNING: YOU ARE USING --tollef. IF THINGS ARE ACTING WEIRD USE --gnu.

It is not clear to me why that flag is set by default. Needless to say, using `--gnu` worked!

Thought I would post this to save someone hours of frustration and confusion.

**EDIT:**
To fix this permanently (in Ubuntu at least), delete the `--tollef` flag in `/etc/parallel/config`

Comment: --tollef will be retired 20140222 http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/parallel/2013-02/msg00018.html It will be helpful if you already now let your frustration be known to your distribution maintainer, so that the default can be changed.

Comment: @Thor what do you mean by 'improving the situation'? As in changing the default behavior?

Comment: @OleTange That is very nice to hear! :)

Comment: Does anyone know what this actully does.  I had this problem and the fix worked.

Comment: This bit me hard. I'm running Ubuntu, and Ubuntu does this by default to everybody. See Launchpad issue [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/parallel/+bug/1183963).

Comment: Just so everyone knows, @OleTange (1st comment above) is the author of Parallel!

Comment: @ElijahLynn It makes it so much easier to predict stuff, when you can make them happen yourself.

Comment: The problem exists and this solves the problem in Fedora 20 as well. Not being able to figure this out prevented me from using `parallel` until now!

Answer (score 18):

Depending on your operating system, you should check whether you're actually running the GNU version.

```
$ parallel --version
parallel: invalid option -- '-'
parallel [OPTIONS] command -- arguments
    for each argument, run command with argument, in parallel
parallel [OPTIONS] -- commands
    run specified commands in parallel
```

If this is the case, you're not running the GNU version.  Ubuntu 12.04 is like this, and you'll need to [manually install GNU parallel](https://askubuntu.com/q/12764/182660) to get the functionality you expect.

Comment: Am using Debian 10 and this is still a problem. You have to manually install parallel, but until you do `parallel` is linked to some useless command that does nothing

Answer (score 1):

Had issues running parallel as an external command from FREEMAT (MATLAB lookalike); the argumentFile was not fed to the command properly solved it by:

- Adding --gnu to options
- Not using cmdString syntax involving ["]

Code:

```
cmdString = 'parallel --gnu command ::: ';
    while j<=jLength
        cmdString = [cmdString argumentFilePath(j,:) ' '];
        j=j+1;
    end
    system(cmdString)
```

Thank you for that :)
Im on Ubuntu 12.04 as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was same issue but different problem. Just running `parallel` command was exiting silently. Also `parallel --version` was saying `invalid option` error. In my Path there was just one parallel executable binary but still it was not detecting.

**I was able to fix it as below**:

1. Run `whereis parallel`. This gives all the paths where executables named **parallel** is present. For my case there was just one path `/usr/local/bin/parallel`. Running using this path works just fine.
2. You can add an alias for this in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file like `alias parallel='/usr/local/bin/parallel'`

And now `parallel` works like charm.

```
dev-dsk % parallel --version         
GNU parallel 20190322
Copyright (C) 2007-2019 Ole Tange and Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
GNU parallel comes with no warranty.
```