# how to find specific binary files with find command and run them in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, find, sh, gnu-parallel

I would like to execute some binary files that have the same names and placed in different directories like this:

```
binary/1/app
binary/2/app
binary/3/app
```

I want to execute app files at the same time. I have created a bash file in a binary directory and written this command  but nothing happened:

```
find . -name app -type f | parallel  -j 4
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you make `sh` the command, then your apps can be the option:

```
parallel sh -- `find . -name app -type f`
```

Answer (score 0):

The command is correct and ought to work. Maybe you are hit by this:
[GNU parallel not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448887/gnu-parallel-not-working-at-all)