# parallel : how to pass options to commands

Tags: gzip, gnu-parallel

For parallelizing gzip compression:

`parallel gzip ::: myfile_*`

does the job but how to pass gzip options such as `-r` or `-9`

I tried `parallel gzip -r -9 ::: myfile_*` and `parallel gzip ::: 9 r myfile_*`

but it doesn't work.

when I tried `parallel "gzip -9 -r" ::: myfile_*`

I get this error message :

`gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression`

Also the `-r` switch for recursively adding directories is not working.

....

Similarly for other commands: how to pass the options while using `parallel` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct syntax:

```
parallel gzip -r -9 ::: myfile_*
```

So something else is wrong. What is the output of

```
parallel --version
```

You can find more about GNU Parallel at: http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/

You can install GNU Parallel in just 10 seconds with:

```
wget -O - pi.dk/3 | sh
```

Watch the intro video on

```
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1
```

Comment: my version is 20121222. I downloaded from fedora repositories. perhaps i should download the latest verstion

Comment: Version 20121222 is fine. But Fedora is known to mess up GNU Parallel for their users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448887/gnu-parallel-not-working-at-all So please post the full output of 'parallel --version' - not just the version number.

Comment: cool... so you are the developer.. well it gives the following output:
`WARNING: YOU ARE USING --tollef. IF THINGS ARE ACTING WEIRD USE --gnu.
GNU parallel 20121222
Copyright (C) 2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012 Ole Tange and Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
GNU parallel comes with no warranty.

Web site: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel

When using GNU Parallel for a publication please cite:

O. Tange (2011): GNU Parallel - The Command-Line Power Too`

Comment: The warning should give you a hint: WARNING: YOU ARE USING --tollef. IF THINGS ARE ACTING WEIRD USE --gnu.

Comment: And did you follow it? (i.e. either remove --tollef or add --gnu)

Comment: My parallel doesn't work with `--version` (get error) and none of the above either (nothing happens) =(

Comment: @antonavy You probably have installed a program called 'parallel' which is not GNU Parallel. Maybe an old version of 'moreutils'? https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/history.html

Answer (score 2):

(I don't think this question belongs here.  Maybe superuser.com?)

`parallel gzip -r -9 ::: *` worked fine for me, going into directories and all.  I am using parallel version 20130622.

Note that with this approach, each directory will be a single task.  You may instead want to pipe the output of `find` to `parallel` to give each file separately to `parallel`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the **--gnu** flag for parallel??

```
parallel -j+0 --gnu "command"....
```

In some systems (like Ubuntu) is disabled by default.