# Executing GNU Parallel within a script

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu, gnu-parallel

The command `parallel echo {} ::: A B C` executed from the command line return the correct result, while when invoked within a bash script return the error:

This is the script:

```
#script.bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

parallel echo {} ::: A B C
```

This is the output:

```
bash script.bash
/bin/bash: {}: command not found
/bin/bash: ::: command not found
/bin/bash: A: command not found
/bin/bash: B: command not found
/bin/bash: C: command not found
```

Any idea why and how to correctly call GNU parallel within a bash script?

Comment: Add the script you are running to the question.

Comment: Edited with script, really basic as you can see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the `--tollef` switch (that does not support the `:::` syntax)  gets enabled when you run it from a script.

You can fix it either by enabling the `--gnu` switch as with

```
parallel --gnu echo {} ::: A B C
```

Comment: For example: parallel echo {} $JOBID ::: $(ls), would produce 1,2,3,4. Similar to LSB_JOBINDEX on LSF

Comment: @memecs No I haven't seen anything like that on gnu parallel. That does not mean that it does not exist though :)

Comment: If it exists it's difficult to find... :). Anyway, thanks a lot for you help

Comment: Well, it could be achieved with: parallel --xapply echo {0} {1} ::: $(ls) ::: $(seq 0 $(ls | wc -l)). Much more teadious though

Comment: See {#} in man. Also walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Comment: @memecs It looks like Ole found what you were looking for

Comment: @user000001 is --tollef enabled even if you've deleted the option from the file /etc/parallel/config or deleted the config file entirely? On my system that doesn't happen (though I was burned by the --tollef flag in the past, before deleting the config file). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16448888/868718

Comment: @SteveKoch It wasn't deleted on my laptop, which is why I was able to reproduce the problem, and answer the question :)

Comment: @user000001 Thanks! I was worried that the flag would be enabled depending on how I ran parallel--good to know that's not the case :)