# Why isn't grepping beginning of lines faster?

Tags: logging, grep

I have huge log files, and I am trying to "filter" them according to their line prefixes. Using `grep` is really fast, but not fast enough; typical results:

```
$ time grep "E ::" app.log

real    0m11.159s
user    0m10.081s
sys     0m1.040s
```

I thought I might save `grep` some effort if I'll tell it that the prefix `E ::` is actually a prefix, that is, it appears in the beginning of the line. I believed that this will let grep skip looking for it along the long lines in my log file. However, as it seems, it doesn't do much:

```
$ time grep "^E ::" app.log

real    0m11.152s
user    0m10.229s
sys     0m0.884s
```

Grepping `^E` is about 15% faster.

Do you have any idea why? Can you think of a faster way to filter these 9GB log files according to the first char in each line?

Comment: Have you tried with huge files, to see if the difference keeps constant or grows in a way? I did test with a file containing `seq 10000000` and the difference is around 3x times.

Comment: The results I've shown are for 9GB log files. I guess the difference will stay constant, if it has stayed constant so far.

Comment: Most single spindle disks run around 100-150MB/s transfer rate if on SATA, and 40MB/s on USB. The fastest RAIDs run around 600MB/s so you are lucky to even read a 9GB file in 11 seconds!!!

Comment: In fact, try this typing the parameters very carefully to measure the disk read speed: `time dd if=app.log of=/dev/null bs=1024k`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: this is done in 0.975s.

Comment: I guess I am saying the answer to your question is that you are I/O bound, not CPU or algorithm bound.

Comment: Ok, there is caching going on here too.

Comment: Could you provide your `grep` version as well (`grep --version`)?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: grep (GNU grep) 2.10

Answer (score 1):

You can try [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html), e.g.

```
cat app.log | parallel --pipe grep '^E ::'
```

See the link for different examples on how to tweak this (how many jobs to run, into how big chunks you want the input file to be split etc.).

Comment: Can't run that code on my machine (missing `-c` argument?)

Comment: @Bach Where does `-c` come from?

Comment: I get quite a lot of `/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument` messages, and nothing happens.

Comment: @Bach GNU `parallel` is a `perl` script so that doesn't make sense, do you actually have the correct program?

Comment: Even running that: `echo "test" | parallel --pipe` gives me 8 such messages. My OS is ubuntu. I believe I have the correct `parallel`.

Comment: @Bach You "believe"? What does `parallel --version` say?

Comment: `GNU parallel 20121122` (and some more stuff).

Comment: Are you hit by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448887/gnu-parallel-not-working-at-all

Comment: @OleTange Looks like that's his issue :-) <OT> Did you see this post by  accident (since it's not tagged) or do you have some magic notifier? Anyway, nice to have you around. I should use your tool more often </OT>.

Comment: @Bach TL;DR: Try `cat app.log | parallel --gnu --pipe grep '^E ::'` and see if it helps.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: I get the line `grep: ::: No such file or directory` many times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LC_ALL=C fgrep "E ::" app.log
```

Comment: Doesn't change much. However, if I try it with `^E`, it becomes 50% slower.

Comment: I had to check it, so for other people reading: [What does “LC_ALL=C” do?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745/40596)

Comment: @fedorqui +1 for your community spirit. I should have explained it myself. It disables NLS so that `grep` can make assumptions about the type of data that it is looking at (e.g. ASCII, single byte etc) and thereby hopefully go faster.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
[honeypot]# (time ls) 1> /dev/null 2> output
[honeypot]# cat output

real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.001s
sys    0m0.006s
```

Comment: What should that do? How does it answer my question?