# Remote rsync in parallel

Tags: ssh, rsync, xargs, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to run rsync over ssh in parallel to transfer files between two machines for evaluation purposes. I wanna see how faster can I get compared to a single rsync process.

I tried these two solutions:
https://wiki.ncsa.illinois.edu/display/~wglick/Parallel+Rsync but with no great success.
https://gist.github.com/rcoup/5358786 (I couldn't make it work)

Based on the [first link](https://wiki.ncsa.illinois.edu/display/~wglick/Parallel+Rsync) I run a command like this:

```
ssh HOST "mkdir -p ~/destdir/basefolder"
cd ./basefolder; ls | xargs -n1 -P 4 -I% rsync -arvuz -e ssh % HOST:~/destdir/basefolder/.
```

and I get the files transfered, but it doesn't seem to work well... In this case, It will run a process for every file and folder in the basefolder, but when it finds a folder, it will transfer everything inside that folder using only 1 process.

I tried to use find -type f, but I got problems because I loose the file hierarchy.

Does anyone how some methods to do what I want? (Use rsync in parallel over ssh while keeping files and folders hierarchy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged your question 'gnu-parallel' the obvious is to refer you to http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Parallelizing-rsync

```
cd src-dir; find . -type f -size +100000 | parallel -v ssh fooserver mkdir -p /dest-dir/{//}\;rsync -Havessh {} fooserver:/dest-dir/{}
```

Comment: Thanks @ole-tange. I tried but I couldn't make it work.
/bin/bash -c mkdir
/bin/bash -c -p
/bin/bash: myserver: command not found
mkdir: missing operand
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.
/bin/bash -c /home/myhome/srcfolder/synced/\{//\}\ 
/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument
/bin/bash: /home/myhome/srcfolder/synced/{//}: No such file or directory
sending incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/home/myhome/497/synced/{}" failed: No such file or directory (2)
sent 12 bytes  received 12 bytes  16.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were...

Comment: @user1891812 are you hit by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448887/gnu-parallel-not-working-at-all/

Comment: That was the problem. I'll include your answer in my tests.