# gnu parallel missing argument to bash?

Tags: bash, semaphore, gnu-parallel

When I try to use gnu parallel's semaphore, any command results in:

```
/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument
```

For instance:

```
parallel --semaphore --verbose sleep 1000
/bin/bash -c 
/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument
```

Why isn't anything getting passed to bash?

Am on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-84-generic x86_64), GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), GNU parallel 20121122.

Comment: Just found that option --gnu to parallel seems to fix this, but have no idea why...

Comment: Are you being hit by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448887/gnu-parallel-not-working-at-all

Comment: @OleTange similar, but in my case the commands don't get executed at all. But the solution is the same. I'll flag as duplicate, but would be nice to leave this here for people trying to search for the symptoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I got to adding the version I was using to my question, I came across this in the version statement. Might be nice if this printed whenever parallel is run (without a --quiet flag or something)!

```
koman@erasmus> parallel --version
WARNING: YOU ARE USING --tollef. IF THINGS ARE ACTING WEIRD USE --gnu.
GNU parallel 20121122
Copyright (C) 2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012 Ole Tange and Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
GNU parallel comes with no warranty.

Web site: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel

When using GNU Parallel for a publication please cite:

O. Tange (2011): GNU Parallel - The Command-Line Power Tool, 
;login: The USENIX Magazine, February 2011:42-47.
```