# Parallel Processing Issue in Python

Tags: python, shell, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a python script `A.py`and it takes arguments with a target file with some `list of IPs` and outs a `CSV` file with Information found regarding the IPs from some sources.`( Run Method : python A.py Input.txt -c Output.csv )`.

It took ages to get the work done. Later,I split Input file `( split -l 1000 Input.txt)` -> created directories ( `10 directories`) -> executed the script with the Input splitted in 10 directories parallel in `screen` mode

How to do this kind of jobs efficiently ? Any suggestions please ?

Comment: you can use python threads for your task

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html

Comment: Thanks Alex will have a look into it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
parallel --round --pipepart -a Input.txt --cat python A.py {} -c {#}.csv
```

If `A.py` can read from a fifo then this is more efficient:

```
parallel --round --pipepart -a Input.txt --fifo python A.py {} -c {#}.csv
```

If your disk has long seek times then it might be faster to use `--pipe` instead of `--pipepart`.

Comment: @ ole Thanks for reply.I cannot see any process running.I get some prompt on the screen " parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit " and What does {#}.csv mean ! Does it mean any CSV file in the directory ?

Comment: Are you being hit by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448887/gnu-parallel-not-working-at-all

Comment: {#} is the substitution string for the job number. So it will pass 1.csv to the first job, 2.csv to the next and so on.