# GNU parallel format

Tags: unix, gnu-parallel

This is a silly question.
I want to apply a "convert ..." operation on a list of files. 
I have been able to successfully apply it using a find operator:

> find $FolderA/ -name "*.dcm" | parallel --will-cite "convert {}
>   -resize %50 $FolderB/{/.}.png"

I want to replicate this command to a specific list of files. I have tried:

> parallel "convert $FolderA/{} -resize %50
>   $FolderB/{/.}.png :::file1 file2 file3...

but it does not work. Parallel just hangs with

> parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do
>   this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit

Any idea what is the right syntax for a list of files?

Comment: What you are doing is correct. Is it an old version installed as a package? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448887/gnu-parallel-not-working-at-all

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
parallel convert "$FolderA/{}" -resize 50% "$FolderB/{/.}.png" ::: file1.dcm file2.dcm
```