# How to pass a command argument to gnu parallel?

Tags: gnu-parallel

Following these instructions[0] I need to append the **l -deu** argument (language flag). I tried appending it quoted to the command **ocrmypdf** below. It fails (output.pdf missing).

`parallel --tag -j 2 ocrmypdf '-l deu' '{}' 'output/{}' ::: *.pdf`

The original command runs without hassle:

`parallel --tag -j 2 ocrmypdf '{}' 'output/{}' ::: *.pdf`

Looking at other answers e.g. [1] didn't help

[0] https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/batch.html

[1] [GNU parallel not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448887/gnu-parallel-not-working-at-all)

Comment: Does `ocrmypdf -l deu foo.pdf output/my.pdf` work? Is there any output on the screen? Can you provide link to a sample.pdf that does not work?

Comment: Yes, everything works, that command as well. Only parallel returns that error

Comment: What error? You have not included the output in your question. Please paste exactly what the output is from your command, and please provide a link to a sample.pdf that does not work. Also paste the output from: `parallel -Dall --tag -j 2 ocrmypdf '-l deu' '{}' 'output/{}' ::: one-of-the-files.pdf` and the output from: `parallel --dr --tag -j 2 ocrmypdf '-l deu' '{}' 'output/{}' ::: one-of-the-files.pdf`