# How to split CSV files as per number of rows specified?

Tags: linux, unix, csv, split

I've CSV file (around 10,000 rows ; each row having 300 columns) stored on LINUX server. 
I want to break this CSV file into 500 CSV files of 20 records each. (Each having same CSV header as present in original CSV)

Is there any linux command to help this conversion?

Comment: This does indeed work, however, the first file's header will be duplicated thus giving the first csv file 2 headers.

Comment: Related: [Split CSV files into smaller files but keeping the headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420966)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a file and keep the first line in each of the pieces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411713/how-to-split-a-file-and-keep-the-first-line-in-each-of-the-pieces)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Made it into a function. You can now call `splitCsv <Filename> [chunkSize]`

```
splitCsv() {
    HEADER=$(head -1 $1)
    if [ -n "$2" ]; then
        CHUNK=$2
    else 
        CHUNK=1000
    fi
    tail -n +2 $1 | split -l $CHUNK - $1_split_
    for i in $1_split_*; do
        sed -i -e "1i$HEADER" "$i"
    done
}
```

Found on: http://edmondscommerce.github.io/linux/linux-split-file-eg-csv-and-keep-header-row.html

Comment: Can you explain the way its working ? I checked the original post but there is also no explanation, and not even an option to post comments.

Comment: what if a cell in CSV contains a newline?

Comment: What kind of newline character is it? It still works for me, on UTF-8, not sure if this helps.

Comment: @shashi009: Assume the original file is called file.txt. 
1: skip the first line, then pipe the rest of the file into `split`, which splits into new files each 20 lines long, with the prefix `split_`
2: iterate through the new split_* files, storing each name to the variable `file`, one at a time
3: for each...
   4: write the first line (column headers) from our original file to a `tmp_file`
   5: append the 20 line split file to `tmp_file`
   6: overwrite the old split_* file with the new `tmp_file`, so it keeps the column headers

Comment: Prepending the header via `echo -e "$HEADER\n$(cat $i)" > $i` is unnecessarily imperformant. I replaced it with `sed -i -e "1i$HEADER" "$i"`.

Comment: splitCsv 15kcontacts.csv 5000
sed: 1: "1i254726770792": command i expects \ followed by text

Comment: It seems to not encode quotes correctly. I also get `sed: 1: "1i"id","Period start"," ...": command i expects \ followed by text`

Answer (score 205):

Use the Linux split command:

```
split -l 20 file.txt new
```

Split the file "file.txt" into files beginning with the name "new" each containing 20 lines of text each.

Type `man split` at the Unix prompt for more information. However you will have to first remove the header from file.txt (using the `tail` command, for example) and then add it back on to each of the split files.

Comment: How can I skip the file.txt first (header) line?

Comment: use `wc -l` to get the number of lines, then take this value subtract 1 (suppose that `wc -l` gave 50) and then run `tail -n 49` (in this example) to get everything except the header line. Note that `wc -l` counts <newline> characters so if the last line does not end in a newline character you will be off by 1 in your number of lines.

Comment: @lucas,  `tail -n +2`  will print all lines but the first.

Comment: @JamesKing, +1 & Thanks! I should read the docs more closely :)

Comment: Point to note: this won't work correctly if you have a column value with newlines in it (such as you get from exporting from Excel or database tables with large blocks of text in them).

Comment: for keep the ".csv"  in new files just add `--additional-suffix=.csv`

Comment: How do I add the header back to each of the files?

Comment: You can also do `split --number=l/500` if you want 500 files of roughly similar size "without splitting lines/records" OR `split --line-bytes=100KB` if you want to have all files less than 100kB, again without lines split across files (cf https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html)

Comment: How to retain the header

Answer (score 37):

One-liner csv splitter which preserves the header row in each split file. This example gives you 999 lines of data  and  one header row per file.

```
cat bigFile.csv | parallel --header : --pipe -N999 'cat >split_file_{#}.csv'
```

for tips on installing parallel, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53062251/401226 where the answer has comments about installing the correct version of parallel for macos and Debian/Ubuntu (in ubuntu use the specifically-named parallel package, which is more recent than what is bundled in moreutils)

Comment: Got Error: parallel not found

Comment: I know this is a linux question, but this is the only one that preserved file extensions and header rows on a Mac. `split` and `splitCsv` just didn't make the cut (pun intended)

Answer (score 31):

This should work !!!

`file_name` = Name of the file you want to split. 
`10000` = Number of rows each split file would contain 
`file_part_` = Prefix of split file name (file_part_0,file_part_1,file_part_2..etc goes on)

> split -d -l 10000 file_name.csv file_part_

Comment: this works absolutely fine! 
Is there a way I can limit the number of 10000 row files i create. Say I just want the first 200,000 rows divided into 10k row csv files and ignore the rest.

Comment: @Pronomita `head -200000 file.csv | split -l 10000 - new_`

Comment: I had a 13 Gb CSV file with a corrupt line at about line ~69 000 000. It was blocking the import into bigquery. This allowed me to split it recursively until I could isolate the line and fix it. No other solution was as efficient in handling large files without bringing the server down or locking things up. Took about 2 minutes to split the file in 5 000 000 row chunks. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this has the same issue as [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20721171/2859408), which also uses `split`: It will fail and mess up the results if your CSV contains cells with embedded newline characters.

`split` will just split them in half, distributing them into two chunks, no matter what.

Answer (score 14):

This should do it for you - all your files will end up called Part1-Part500.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=10000.csv
HDR=$(head -1 $FILENAME)   # Pick up CSV header line to apply to each file
split -l 20 $FILENAME xyz  # Split the file into chunks of 20 lines each
n=1
for f in xyz*              # Go through all newly created chunks
do
   echo $HDR > Part${n}    # Write out header to new file called "Part(n)"
   cat $f >> Part${n}      # Add in the 20 lines from the "split" command
   rm $f                   # Remove temporary file
   ((n++))                 # Increment name of output part
done
```

Comment: This created the files but tabs (I mean \t) were replaced with spaces, and my CSV files were using \t as separator

Comment: This can be improved slightly by padding the numbers so that the files are displayed consecutively automatically. By replacing the ${n} with $(printf "%05d\n" $n)

Comment: Header line is duplicated in the first file.

Comment: @JuhaPalomäki - Fixed that issue in an edit.

Comment: Note that this has the same issue as [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20721171/2859408), which also uses `split`: It will fail and mess up the results if your CSV contains cells with embedded newline characters.

`split` will just split them in half, distributing them into two chunks, no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked many years ago, but for future readers I'd like to mention that the most convenient tool for this purpose is `xsv` from https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv

The `split` sub-command is meant to do exactly what has been asked in the original question. The documentation says:

```
split - Split one CSV file into many CSV files of N chunks
```

Each of the split chunks retains the header row.