# parallelize conversion of a single 16M row csv to Parquet with dask

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, parquet, dask

The following operation works, but takes nearly 2h:

```
from dask import dataframe as ddf
ddf.read_csv('data.csv').to_parquet('data.pq')
```

Is there a way to parallelize this?

The file `data.csv` is ~2G uncompressed with 16 million rows by 22 columns.

Comment: Can you please tell us the size `data.csv`?

Comment: @user32185 2G uncompressed with 16 million rows by 22 columns.

Comment: Can you tell me the types of your data?

Comment: The problem is that you are writing it in one single file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is a problem with data or not. I made a toy example on my machine and the same command takes ~9 seconds

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask
client = Client()
# if you wish to connect to the dashboard
client

# fake df size ~2.1 GB
# takes ~180 seconds
N = int(5e6)
df = pd.DataFrame({i: np.random.rand(N) 
                   for i in range(22)})
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)

# the following takes ~9 seconds on my machine
dd.read_csv("data.csv").to_parquet("data_pq")
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing out multiple CSV files in parallel is also easy with the `repartition` method:

```py
df = dd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df.repartition(npartitions=20)
df.to_parquet('./data_pq', write_index=False, compression='snappy')
```

Dask likes working with partitions that are around 100 MB, so 20 partitions should be good for a 2GB dataset.

You could also speed this up, by splitting the CSV before reading it, so Dask can read the CSV files in parallel.  You could use [these tactics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721120/how-to-split-csv-files-as-per-number-of-rows-specified) to break up the 2GB CSV into 20 different CSVs and then write them out without repartitioning:

```py
df = dd.read_csv('folder_with_small_csvs/*.csv')
df.to_parquet('./data_pq', write_index=False, compression='snappy')
```

Answer (score 0):

`read_csv` has a `blocksize` parameter ([docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv)) that you can use to control the size of the resulting partition and hence, the number of partitions. That, from what I understand, will result in reading the partitions in parallel - each worker will read block size at relevant offset.

You can set `blocksize` so that it yields the required number of partition to take advantage of the cores you have. For example

```py
cores = 8
size = os.path.getsize('data.csv')
ddf = dd.read_csv("data.csv", blocksize=np.rint(size/cores))
print(ddf.npartitions)
```

Will output:

> 8

Better yet, you can try to modify the size so that the resulting parquet has partitions of recommended size (which I have seen different numbers in different places :-|).