# Concatenating a dask dataframe and a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a dask dataframe (`df`) with around 250 million rows (from a 10Gb CSV file). I have another pandas dataframe (`ndf`) of 25,000 rows. I would like to add the first column of pandas dataframe to the dask dataframe by repeating every item 10,000 times each.

Here's the code that I tried. I have reduced the problem to a smaller size.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(25000, 2)).to_csv("tempfile.csv")
df = dd.read_csv("tempfile.csv")
ndf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, 3500, size=2500))
df['Node'] = np.repeat(ndf[0], 10)
```

With this code, I end up with an error.

> ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.

I can perform a `reset_index()` followed by a `set_index()` to make `df.known_divisions` `True` for the dask dataframe. But it is a time consuming operation. Is there a better faster way to do what I am trying to do? Can I do this using pandas itself?

The end goal is to find rows from `ndf` where any of the corresponding rows from `df` matches some criteria.

Comment: Hi Najeem, were you able to check my proposed solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your basic algorithm is "I'd like the first 10 values of `df['Node']` to be set to the first value of `ndf`, the next 10 values to the next value of `ndf`, and so on". The reason this is hard in Dask, is because it doesn't know how many rows are in each partition: you are reading from CSVs, and the number of rows you get in X bytes depends on exactly what the data are like in each part. Other formats give you more information...

You will, therefore, certainly need two passes through the data. You could work with the index, to figure out divisions and potentially do some sorting. To my mind, the easiest thing you can do is simply to measure the division lengths, and so get the offset of the start of each:

```
lengths = df.map_partitions(len).compute()
offsets = np.cumsum(lengths.values)
offsets -= offsets[0]
```

and now use custom delayed function to work on the parts

```
@dask.delayed
def add_node(part, offset, ndf):
    index = pd.Series(range(offset, offset + len(part)) // 10,
                      index=part.index)  # 10 is the repeat factor
    part['Node'] = index.map(ndf)
    return part

df2 = dd.from_delayed([add_node(d, off, ndf) 
                       for d, off in zip(df.to_delayed(), offsets)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using you same workflow you can manually set `divisions` as suggested [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1848#issuecomment-267138530)

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(25000, 2)).to_csv("tempfile.csv", index=False)
df = dd.read_csv("tempfile.csv")
ndf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, 3500, size=2500))


df.divisions = (0, len(df)-1)
df["Note"] = dd.from_array(np.repeat(ndf.values, 10))
```

I don't think using `np.repeat` is very efficient in particular for big df.

Comment: The example ran fine, however, when I tried it on the original dataframe, the line `df.divisions = (0, len(df)-1)` took half n hour to run. I am assuming my filtering operations would take similar time. I think the `reset_index()` and `set_index()` also would take similar time.

Comment: I guess the problem here is `len(df)`. Do you mind to run just that to see the timing? Working with so big csv file could be a problem too. Have you tried to split into several smaller files? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20721120/4819376)

Comment: Yea, that's how I solved the problem for the timebeing. But it's not a scalable method. I could as well use chunks in pandas. But I wanted to use dask so that I could scale the problem really quickly (using other machines on my network).

Comment: I did the same mistake when starting to use dask, and I saw that colleagues that are using spark are facing the same problems. It is actually worth to spend time nicely partitioning your data and save it on a columnar format as `parquet`. Then using the very same dask command you could see a performance boost.