# How to split a csv into multiple csv files using Dask

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dask-distributed

How to split a csv file into multiple files using Dask?

The bellow code seems to write to one file only which takes a long time to write the full thing. I believe writing to multiple files will be faster.

```
import dask.dataframe as ddf
import dask
file_path = "file_name.csv"
df   = ddf.read_csv(file_path)
futs = df.to_csv(r"*.csv", compute=False)
_, l = dask.compute(futs, df.size)
```

Comment: Have you considered splitting it using [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48154590/4819376)? It might be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that when you read `df` you have `df.npartitions` is just `1`.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

file_path = "file_name.csv"
df = dd.read_csv(file_path)
# set how many file you would like to have
# in this case 10
df = df.repartition(npartitions=10)
df.to_csv("file_*.csv")
```

But as far as I can see it's not faster.