# Large csv to parquet using Dask - OOM

Tags: dask

I've 7 csv files with 8 GB each and need to convert to parquet.

Memory usage goes to 100 GB and I had to kill it .
I tried with Distributed Dask as well . The memory is limited to 12 GB but no output produced for long time.
FYI. I used to traditional pandas with Chunking + Prod consumer --> was able to convert in 30 mins
What I'm missing for Dask processing ?

```
def ProcessChunk(df,...):
    df.to_parquet()     

for factfile in fArrFileList:
   df = dd.read_csv(factfile, blocksize="100MB",
                 dtype=fColTypes, header=None, sep='|',names=fCSVCols)
   result = ProcessChunk(df,output_parquet_file, chunksize, fPQ_Schema, fCSVCols, fColTypes)
```

Comment: Hi, i'm not really into python and dask, but the problem of loading large files is quite common. Take a look here maybe https://pythondata.com/dask-large-csv-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for suggestions. map_partitions worked.

```
df = dd.read_csv(filename, blocksize="500MB",
                     dtype=fColTypes, header=None, sep='|',names=fCSVCols)
df.map_partitions(DoWork,output_parquet_file, chunksize, Schema, CSVCols, fColTypes).compute(num_workers=2)
```

But the same approach for Dask Distributed Local Cluster didn't work well.when the csv size < 100 MB it worked in local cluster mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I found that use dask to split to smallest parquet is very slow and will eventually fail. If you have access to a Linux Terminal you can use parallel or split. For an example of their usage check answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721120/how-to-split-csv-files-as-per-number-of-rows-specified)

My workflow is supposing your files are called `file1.csv,..., file7.csv` and are stored in `data/raw`. I'm assuming you are using the terminal commands from your notebook and this is the reason I'm adding the `%%bash` magic

- create folders `data/raw_part/part1/,... ,data/raw_part/part7/`

```
%%bash
for year in {1..7}
do
mkdir -p data/raw_parts/part${i}
done
```

- for each file run (in case you want to use parallel)

````
%%bash
cat data/raw/file1.csv | parallel --header : --pipe -N1000000 'cat >data/raw_parts/part1/file_{#}.csv'```
````

## convert files to parquet

1. first create output folders

```
%%bash
for year in {1..7}
do
mkdir -p data/processed/part${i}
done
```

2. define function to convert csv to parquet

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
from dask import delayed, compute

# this can run in parallel
@delayed
def convert2parquet(fn, fldr_in, fldr_out):
    fn_out = fn.replace(fldr_in, fldr_out)\
               .replace(".csv", ".parquet")

    df = pd.read_csv(fn)
    df.to_parquet(fn_out, index=False)
```

3. get all files you want to convert

```py
jobs = []
fldr_in = "data/raw_parts/"
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(fldr_in):
    if len(filenames) > 0:
        jobs += [os.path.join(dirpath, fn)
                 for fn in filenames]
```

4. process all in parallel

```py
%%time
to_process = [convert2parquet(job, fldr_in, fldr_out) for job in jobs]
out = compute(to_process)
```