# Splitting CSV file into multiple sheets in an Excel file based on row limit argument

Tags: python, csv, utility

Hi I am trying to run a utility script i found in github 
https://gist.github.com/Athmailer/4cdb424f03129248fbb7ebd03df581cd

Update 1:
Hi I modified the logic a bit more so that rather than splitting the csv into multiple csvs again i am creating a single excel file with multiple sheets containing the splits. Below is my code

```
import os
import csv
import openpyxl
import argparse

def find_csv_filenames( path_to_dir, suffix=".csv" ):
    filenames = os.listdir(path_to_dir)
    return [ filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith( suffix ) ]

def is_binary(filename):
    """
    Return true if the given filename appears to be binary.
    File is considered to be binary if it contains a NULL byte.
    FIXME: This approach incorrectly reports UTF-16 as binary.
    """
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for block in f:
            if '\0' in block:
                return True
    return False

def split(filehandler, delimiter=',', row_limit=5000,
    output_name_template='.xlsx', output_path='.', keep_headers=True):

class MyDialect(csv.excel):
    def __init__(self, delimiter=','):
        self.delimiter = delimiter
    lineterminator = '\n'

my_dialect = MyDialect(delimiter=delimiter)
reader = csv.reader(filehandler, my_dialect)

index = 0
current_piece = 1

# Create a new Excel workbook
# Create a new Excel sheet with name Split1
current_out_path = os.path.join(
     output_path,
     output_name_template
)
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet(index=index, title="Split" + str(current_piece))
current_limit = row_limit

if keep_headers:
    headers = reader.next()
    ws.append(headers)

for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    if i + 1 > current_limit:
        current_piece += 1
        current_limit = row_limit * current_piece
        ws = wb.create_sheet(index=index, title="Split" + str(current_piece))
        if keep_headers:
            ws.append(headers)
    ws.append(row)

wb.save(current_out_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Splits a CSV file into multiple pieces.',
                                     prefix_chars='-+')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--row_limit', type=int, default=5000,
                        help='The number of rows you want in each output file. (default: 5000)')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    #Check if output path exists else create new output folder
    output_path='Output'
    if not os.path.exists(output_path):
        os.makedirs(output_path)

    with open('Logger.log', 'a+') as logfile:
        logfile.write('Filename --- Number of Rows\n')
        logfile.write('#Unsplit\n')
        #Get list of all csv's in the current folder
        filenames = find_csv_filenames(os.getcwd())
        filenames.sort()
        rem_filenames = []
        for filename in filenames:
            if is_binary(filename):
                logfile.write('{} --- binary -- skipped\n'.format(filename))
                rem_filenames.append(filename)
            else:
                with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
                    reader_file = csv.reader(infile,delimiter=";",lineterminator="\n")
                    value = len(list(reader_file))
                    logfile.write('{} --- {} \n'.format(filename,value))

        filenames = [item for item in filenames if item not in rem_filenames]
        filenames.sort()
        logfile.write('#Post Split\n')
        for filename in filenames:
            #try:
            with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
                name = filename.split('.')[0]
                split(filehandler=infile,delimiter=';',row_limit=args.row_limit,output_name_template= name + '.xlsx',output_path='Output')
```

I have a folder called 'CSV Files' which contains a lot of csv's which need to be split. 
I am keeping this utility script in the same folder

Getting the following error on running the script:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv_split.py", line 96, in <module>
    split(filehandler=infile,delimiter=';',row_limit=args.row_limit,output_name_template= name + '.xlsx',output_path='Output')
  File "csv_split.py", line 57, in split
    ws.append(row)
  File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 790, in append
    cell = Cell(self, row=row_idx, col_idx=col_idx, value=content)
  File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.value = value
  File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 294, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 191, in _bind_value
    value = self.check_string(value)
  File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 156, in check_string
    raise IllegalCharacterError
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError
```

Can some one let me know if i have to add another for loop and go each cell in the row and append it to the sheet or can it be done in a single go. Also I seem to have made this logic a lot clumsy can this be optimized further.

Folder structure for your reference

[image]

Comment: The usage message clearly tells you that you should pass the file name alone, without any `input_file=` things: `python2 splitter.py 'Sports & Outdoors 2017-08-26'`

Comment: if you are using ubuntu I think its more wise to `blash` split into of any python script. [split file using ubuntu terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12172/split-a-large-file-into-smaller-files-and-then-integrate-them-to-get-the-origina)

Comment: @AnuragMisra Will the command-line `split` also carry the headers into the splitted parts?

Comment: @DYZ yes.! [split file by keeping header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411713/how-to-split-a-file-and-keep-the-first-line-in-each-of-the-pieces)

Answer (score 0):

You must pass just a name of the file as command line argument:

```
python splitter.py 'Sports & Outdoors 2017-08-26'
```

Also, I tried running the above script and no matter on what CSS I run it, it doesn't return the first line (which should normally be a header) although `keep_headers = True`. Setting `keep_headers = False` also prints out the header line, which is a bit counterintuitive.

This script is meant to read a single CSV. If you want to read every CSV in a directory, you want to make another script that will loop through all the files in that directory.

```
import splitter as sp
import os

files = [ f for f in os.listdir('/your/directory') if f[-4:] == '.csv' ]
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        sp.split(f)
```