# Splitting CSV in mac

Tags: csv, split

Is there a way to split a 50 GB CSV file into multiple CSV file each with 1GB of data and make sure its gzip?

I tried to do

```bash
cat test.csv  | split -b 1000000000g -d -a4 - output_prefix --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz'
```

```
    usage: split [-l line_count] [-a suffix_length] [file [prefix]]
           split -b byte_count[K|k|M|m|G|g] [-a suffix_length] [file [prefix]]
           split -n chunk_count [-a suffix_length] [file [prefix]]
           split -p pattern [-a suffix_length] [file [prefix]]
```

but it gave an error.

Comment: "split a 50 GB CSV file into multiple CSV file" do you want each of the files to be valid CSV files?  Because it is unlikely spitting into 1GB chunks will never divide one of the lines between two files (unless you have some good reason to believe otherwise).

Comment: Hi there yes. basically I need to break up this 50GB CSV files into multiple CSV files (which are gzip) each of size 1 GB.

Comment: You wrote `- output_prefix`, but weren't you willing to write `-output_prefix` or `--output_prefix`? it seems that there is a extra blank space here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot split exactly by size and simultaneously have a valid CSV, with all the cells filled in, in the last record.

If it is possible and you can change your approach, you could break it down by number of records, using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/installing-miller/) and [split verb](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/reference-verbs/index.html#split):

```
mlr --csv --from input.csv split -n 1000000
```

In output you get split_1.csv, split_2.csv, ..., each made up of 1000000 records.

Each one will be valid CSV.

Comment: Ah thats great. How do i save this to a folder path?

Comment: @Adam starting from your output folder, run something like this `mlr --csv --from /tmp/sample/input.csv split -n 1000000`, pointing to the absolute path of the input file

Comment: Hm i notice its a little slow to splut a 50 GB file. I tried this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411713/how-to-split-a-file-and-keep-the-first-line-in-each-of-the-pieces/53062251#53062251

Comment: okay, if you've solved it, I won't add any more alternatives

Comment: @Adam  Your solution works, if you do not have any carriage return in CSV cells

Answer (score 0):

I haven't the complete answer. But it's to give you the principle.
I'm used to gather (the contrary of you) csv, or to take a sample from one with the help of a `grep`, to create another csv.

The principle for all these tasks, and yours, is to extract first in two separate temp files:

- a temporary `$header_file`, with only the header of your csv
- a temporary `$row_file` with all the rows of your csv, and not the header

I do this that way, with **$1** the csv file you want to handle:

```bash
header_file=$(mktemp)
rows_file=$(mktemp)

awk 'FNR>1' "$1" > "$rows_file"
awk 'FNR<2' "$1" > "$header_file"
```

Then, you split your `$rows_file` in parts in another temp files,
let's call each of them: `$part_file`,

and you concatenate them in valid partials csv files with a:

```bash
cat "$header_file" "$part_file" >"$part_file.csv"
```

for each part containing rows that you've separated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps. But I eventually just did this. Now i just need to figure out to save as csv.gv files

```
 split  -b 1000000000 -a4 test.csv tmp/
```